# Difficulty getting "List group members" to return correct Sharepoint group information in Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to write a simple flow to notify an entire Sharepoint group when a new document has been added to a section of the site.  This is the solution I've been working on:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/fotw-members-your-office365-groups/

Everything works well, but when testing, the "List group members" action is only returning the users in the site owners group.  The only option in the dropdown is the site name, nothing specific to user groups.  I can choose "Enter custom value," but I am not able to get that to work.  I've tried the hexidecimal Group ID for both the "Everyone except external users" and the "Members" group, but it returns a 404 error.  I've also tried just typing in the group name (even though I'm sure that's not specific enough as our company has many Sharepoint sites/groups).  Nothing has worked so far.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the "List group members" action can only get Office 365 groups instead of SharePoint Groups.

To send email to sharepoint groups, you could use the rest API. For more, you could refer to this article:
https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/email-a-sharepoint-group-from-a-flow/